# PHP RegEx: Replace all relative paths in HTML-string, with absolute paths

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I'm working on a project where I need to scrape some content from the same site, but a subfolder, and store it. I know it's not  ideal, but it's sadly the best approach for the client.

**I need to change all references from relative to absolute URLs**
All the references (images, css, js) are referred relatively with both:

- "../../imgs/"
- "/js/"

... which means they don't work in my sub-folder. I need a function that matches the regex on these references and replaces the path.

When I try this:

```
function getRelativeContent($url) {
    $page = file_get_contents($url);

    //url needs trailing /
    if (substr($url, -1, 1) != "/")
        $url .= "/";

    $page = preg_replace('/src="(\/)?([\w_\-\/\.\?&=@%#]*)"/i','src="' . $url . '$2"', $page);
    $page = preg_replace('/href="(\/)?([\w_\-\/\.\?&=@%#]*)"/i','href="' . $url . '$2"', $page);

    return $page;
}

echo getRelativeContent($url);
```

Then these URLs doesn't work:

```
<link href="/cassette.axd/stylesheet/fdbdaa59cb97b35f06f65fd41cb60caa3975cc0f/forbrug-rwd_(max-width 767px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 767px)">

<img src="https://www.domain.dk/~/media/2561BD6AFBD64402877E4ACED01F97FD.ashx" />
```

Comment: Can you post some examples

Comment: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-absolute-link-urls.htm or http://99webtools.com/blog/convert-relative-path-into-absolute-url/

Comment: I've made it work (kinda), it doesn't work on all links, somehow... :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getRelativeContent($url) {
    $page = file_get_contents($url);

    //url needs trailing /
    if (substr($url, -1, 1) != "/")
        $url .= "/";

    $page = preg_replace('/src="(\/)?([\w_\-\/\.\?&=@%#]*)"/i','src="' . $url . '$2"', $page);
    $page = preg_replace('/href="(\/)?([\w_\-\/\.\?&=@%#]*)"/i','href="' . $url . '$2"', $page);

    return $page;
}

echo getRelativeContent($url);
```